# Multi threading in pure C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11, mingw

Let me clarify that I am aware of multi-threading support being added to c++11.
But before this update, multi-threading could be done in Qt in C++ only. So,

1. How Qt could provide this functionality & not the standard C++?
2. How did people multi-thread their 'pure' C++ (no libraries like Qt, FLTK+) applications?
   I am interested in people using the MinGW compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt uses different threading libraries for the different operating systems. For example, on Unix, you can use pthreads, and on Windows you can use WinAPI support (like `CreateThread` function).

For example, Qt uses this code to create a thread on Unix systems:

```
 int code =
    pthread_create(&d->thread_id, &attr, QThreadPrivate::start, this);
```

and this to create it on Windows system:

```
 d->handle = (Qt::HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, d->stackSize, QThreadPrivate::start,
                                        this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &(d->id));
```

All this is wrapped using preprocessor, so the right library is used for the right system. Take a look at this code inside `qthread_p.h` and everything should be clear to yo:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_UNIX
    pthread_t thread_id;
    QWaitCondition thread_done;

    static void *start(void *arg);
#if defined(Q_OS_SYMBIAN)
    static void finish(void *arg, bool lockAnyway=true, bool closeNativeHandle=true);
#else
    static void finish(void *);
#endif

#endif // Q_OS_UNIX

#if defined(Q_OS_WIN32) || defined(Q_OS_WINCE)
    HANDLE handle;
    unsigned int id;
    int waiters;

    static unsigned int __stdcall start(void *);
    static void finish(void *, bool lockAnyway=true);
#endif // Q_OS_WIN32
```

To answer your questions:

1. Already answered. Thread support in C++11 implementations is implemented in the same way (with a small difference - gcc doesn't need to support Win32 threads, nor the Microsoft VC needs to support pthreads if they are written only for one system. Qt is multiplatform library so it needs to include support for all platforms).
2. Using low-level system calls like (`pthread_create`, `CreateThread`, etc).

Comment: Hi Nemanja,
Thanks for your prompt reply!
Now I understand that Qt uses libraries from OS for multi threading.
So in C++11 does the same thing happen?

Comment: @Cool_Coder yes, standard library needs to use different, OS specific, calls to support threading on the different systems.

Comment: Yes, C++11 will place the onus on the implementor to provide threading libraries backed by the native OS library

Comment: So, if I multi-thread in a pure C++11 application compiled with MinGW I would now have to use include OS specific headers. Now the resulting target would automatically fetch the required OS libraries (dependencies) at run time or I have to ship them with my application?

Comment: In my experience in the past, MinGW worked fine without shipping MS C++ Redistributables.  But that just means a build for Windows XP should work on Windows 7, and 8 (or vice versa), and you still would need to compile on Linux or OSX for it to work on the the other OS's.

Answer (score 5):

> How Qt could provide this functionality & not the standard C++?

That's similar to asking how Qt could provide the ability to show GUI windows when that functionality isn't provided by C++. Qt isn't implemented purely in terms of the C++ standard library; Qt implements fundamentally new functionality by using other things.

> How did people multi-thread their 'pure' C++ (no libraries like Qt, FLTK+) applications? I am interested in people using the MinGW compiler.

Prior to C++11 they did not. They had to use other libraries such as pthreads or OS specific libraries. In fact prior to the C++11 memory model multi-threaded programs were all 'undefined behavior' according to the spec.

Comment: *"prior to the C++11 memory model multi-threaded programs were all 'undefined behavior' according to the spec.*" Can you explain that? The C++ memory model makes multithreaded programs have undefined-behavior?

Comment: @Manu343726 Prior to C++11 the C++ memory model did not define the behavior of objects accessed from multiple threads, so the behavior of doing so was undefined. As a result the C++ spec imposed no requirements on any program which did so.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing Qt was doing is to use different libraries depending on the platform. The standard library is a set of libraries too, but with a common and well specified behavior and interfaces for all of the platforms.

Comment: @Cool_Coder I'm glad I could help you :), but avoid this kind of comments: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126184/222868. If an answer was useful for you, reflect it with an upvote.